# Is it possible to make a BeagleBone Black app on Visual Studio without VisualGDB?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, beagleboneblack

We are currently doing a minor for our study where we need to be able to connect a screen to a BeagleBone Black. The goal is to recreate a gameboy. We currently flashed the latest version of Debian on it, which is **Debian 8.4**. The (mandatory) requirements of our project are:

- It is required to use **Visual Studio** for further development, because other students will also use our project.
- **We can use any language**, but it is preferred for us to use C++.
- **We can't use VisualGDB**, because school does not fund this and the free trial lasts 30 days, while our teacher expects to be working on this project with other students for at least a few years.

We have already tried:

- Creating a **Node.js** application that we can debug through Visual Studio with this [tutorial](https://bitstobrowser.wordpress.com/2015/12/04/using-visual-studio-to-remote-debug-a-node-js-application-on-a-beaglebone-black/). With this method we are limited to one language and we can't use C++. We can not debug the code immediately, since we need to transfer the files to the BeagleBone first and then debug it.
- Using **Windows CE 7** image from Codeplex. We got this recommendation from our teacher, but we do not know how to proceed any further and connect Visual Studio on this way.

We see a lot of tutorials on the internet for our issue that require to download VisualGDB. Is there any other way to continue this assignment?

Comment: The path of least resistance may be to jettison Visual Studio, especially since you appear to be on a budget. The linaro toolchain has its warts, but integrates well with Eclipse and tutorials abound.

Answer (score 0):

VisualGDB is obsolete since Visual Studio 2015.
It is possible to cross-compile via a **free** addon: https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/725025cf-7067-45c2-8d01-1e0fd359ae6e

This will give you the full benefit of writing your C++ code in Visual Studio and still deploy to a Linux based machine.

More information about the use of the addon:
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2016/03/30/visual-c-for-linux-development/

Sounds like a cool project, good luck with it!